# Assign a class to document.createElement('img')

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How do I assign the `.rotatable` class to the below img element instead of having `('src', 'rotate.png')`?

```
$(document.createElement('img')).attr('src', 'rotate.png')
```

css:

```
.rotatable {
    cursor: move;
    background-image: url(rotate.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to use `document.createElement()` at all since you're using jQuery:

```
var img = $("<img/>", {
  "class": "rotatable",
  "src": "rotate.png"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to add a class with jQuery, you can:

```
$('img').addClass('rotatable');
```